# show image from database sqlite

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite

i've saome problem with my application
i have code like this

```
Cursor cur=helper.getGamb(almagId);
cur.moveToFirst();
if(cur.getString(1).equals("")){
detGam.setImageResource(R.drawable.gambarnf);
}else detGam.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(cur.getString(1)));
return Drawable.createFromPath(cur.getString(1));
```

but i have error like this

```
02-14 14:02:16.623: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16468): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-14 14:02:16.623: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16468):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
02-14 14:02:16.623: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16468):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
02-14 14:02:16.623: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16468):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
02-14 14:02:16.623: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16468):     at com.sat.alfaloc.Detail.load(Detail.java:186)
02-14 14:02:16.623: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16468):     at com.sat.alfaloc.Detail.onCreate(Detail.java:100)
02-14 14:02:16.623: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16468):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-14 14:02:16.623: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16468):     ... 11 more
```

what should i do to repair this??thank you :)

Comment: first you need to check the count of the cursor . Please use cur.getCount() method and see how many records are in cursor. Becuase as your error occurs , it might be there are no records in cursor .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//assuming that you have fetched the data using cursor:
byte[] image1 = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("image_data"));
imageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image1, 0, image1.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you store image path instead of image in database.Access those images using image path that is stored in database.

Comment: yes i save path image,,but i save this path in other table with other data..i want retrieve this path in to my application,but i have an error in this part `detGam.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(cur.getString(1)))`..you can tell me to repair this code??thank you

Comment: get Drawable like this "detGam.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(cur.getString(cur.getColumnName("your column name))));"  this means take value using your column name